Attendance Machine Integration to Laravel 10
Hi i have a problem with syncronize data from my attendance machine to my webapp, i'm currently using Laravel 10 with PHP 8.1, the connection is successful but it returns an empty string, and heres my code
 public function tarikDataAbsen(AttendanceMachineInformation $attendanceMachineInformation): JsonResponse
    {
        $ip = $attendanceMachineInformation->ip_address;
        $port = $attendanceMachineInformation->port;
        $key = $attendanceMachineInformation->key;

        $connect = fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 1);
        dd($connect);
        $buffer = "";
        if ($connect) {
            $soapRequest = "<GetAttLog><ArgComKey xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">" . $key . "</ArgComKey><Arg><PIN xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">All</PIN></Arg></GetAttLog>";
            $newLine = "\r\n";
            fwrite($connect, "POST /iWsService HTTP/1.0" . $newLine);
            fwrite($connect, "Content-Type: text/xml" . $newLine);
            fwrite($connect, "Content-Length: " . strlen($soapRequest) . $newLine . $newLine);
            fwrite($connect, $soapRequest . $newLine);
            while ($response = fgets($connect, 1024)) {
                $buffer .= $response;
            }
        } else {
            echo "Koneksi Gagal";
        }

        $buffer = $this->parseData($buffer, "<GetAttLogResponse>", "</GetAttLogResponse>");
//        dd($buffer);
        $buffer = explode("\r\n", $buffer);

        $export = [];
        for ($a = 0, $aMax = count($buffer); $a < $aMax; $a++) {
            $data = $this->parseData($buffer[$a], "<Row>", "</Row>");
            $export[$a]['pin'] = $this->parseData($data, "<PIN>", "</PIN>");
            $export[$a]['waktu'] = $this->parseData($data, "<DateTime>", "</DateTime>");
            $export[$a]['status'] = $this->parseData($data, "<Status>", "</Status>");
        }
        return response()->json($export);
    }

private function parseData($data, $p1, $p2): string
{
    $data = ' ' . $data;
    $hasil = '';
    $awal = strpos($data, $p1);
    if ($awal != '') {
        $akhir = strpos(strstr($data, $p1), $p2);
        if ($akhir != '') {
            $hasil = substr($data, ($awal + strlen($p1)), ($akhir - strlen($p1)));
        }
    }

    return $hasil;
}

when i dd the $connect

and when i dd the fgets function it return false, somebody can help ? thanks.
I tried using ZKLib but it took to long to response

check here why u are being blocked.

im ended up using https://github.com/jmrashed/zkteco, and its work fine. thanks
